# Connection blocked because server only allows public key authentication

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm new to using git, and I'm trying to connect to my repo on GitLab.
I keep getting the following error message:

> Received disconnect from 35.231.145.151 port 22:2: Connection blocked
>   because server only allows public key authentication. Please contact
>   your network administrator. Disconnected from 35.231.145.151 port 22
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

I've tried to add a new public key, as well as remove the known hosts file and have gitlab added to a new one. Nothing seems to work.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have good suggestion in error message: "Please contact your network administrator". **Do it!**

Comment: Start debugging with `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com`

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Anyone has a solution for it?

Comment: Isn't there a firewall in between? I guess the main problem is an aggressive firewall between your machine and the server. Please check with your network administrator to fix this issue, because it looks like something network-based. The error does not belong to GitLab or SSH (which Git uses for connections). This looks like a problem like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1466177/connection-blocked-because-server-only-allows-public-key-authentication-putty-f)

Comment: Note that sometimes the "network administrator" is your ISP

Comment: I got the same problem and googled a lot. The closest solution is hinted by this link [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1307364/connection-blocked-because-server-only-allows-public-key-authentication-please](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1307364/connection-blocked-because-server-only-allows-public-key-authentication-please).

Comment: However, **no** explicit solution is given, only a quoted comment from another site (the given link no longer valid) was given:


**"Finally the problem was our Firewall. After an upgrade a ssh_certificate_deep_inspection feature got activated and caused all the problems. "**
   

I hope someone is able to come up with a fix.   It bothers me a lot: because of the problem I can only login via password (just on a particulr net, everything is fine at home), I cant use for example ansible etc.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the error happened because of SSL/SSH inspection on the firewall, please check with your network administrator to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the SSL/SSH lead but it didn't work for me.
In my case changing the `.ssh/config` (for mac check `/Users/<username>/.ssh/config`) `PreferredAuthentications` value from

`PreferredAuthentications publickey`

to the default values

`PreferredAuthentications hostbased,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password,gssapi-with-mic` did the job.

---

A colleague also mentioned that for some it might be from SSL cerificates (so is probably still a lead to take). As a direction for this case: on mac you can try to press command+space, type `Keychain Access` and try to find what certificate blocks your connection and either double click and check if editing the trust will fix it or delete the certificate.