# ssh won't log in today(!) with public key - debug gives strange output

Tags: ssh

*"Nothing has changed since Friday."* **But see below.** This morning(!), Bitbucket.org rejects my `ssh` attempt with:

```
Connection blocked because server only allows public key authentication. 
Please contact your network administrator.
```

I followed another suggestion here and tried `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` (this being the userid shown by `git remote -v` and in the output saw this oddity:

***Edit:*  Here is the *complete* output:**

```
$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-F8PhcLGt2yVB/agent.11836; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=11837; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 11837;

$ ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [18.205.93.0] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_31073e5a11 app-191
debug1: no match: conker_31073e5a11 app-191
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:6tASx4IX+FSngemFsQuAIyt0aQ/+fMAyzXBRWRajoBM
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:6tASx4IX+FSngemFsQuAIyt0aQ/+fMAyzXBRWRajoBM.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/mike/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /home/mike/.ssh/known_hosts:2
  remove with:
  ssh-keygen -f "/home/mike/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "bitbucket.org"
RSA host key for bitbucket.org has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

However:  the `.ssh` directory *does* exist, its permissions are `-r--------`, the `id_rsa` (and `id_rsa.pub`) files both exist, and their permissions likewise are correct.  `ssh-agent` was restarted.

```
ls -ld /home/mike/.ssh/id_rsa
-r-------- 1 mike mike 1679 Oct 24 10:41 /home/mike/.ssh/id_rsa
(notice the date ... many months ago ... correct)

cat /home/mike/.ssh/id_rsa
(the correct private key is displayed ...) (ditto public-key)
```

Again:  "nothing has changed since Friday."  I think I've thought of everything!  So, what the heck could still be wrong?  And why did this suddenly start happening, both to me and to colleagues, *today?*  (Nothing in `/etc/ssh` has changed in many months.  Likewise the certificates in `~/.ssh`, which as previously noted does have correct permissions.)

***Another Edit:* Here's what happens when I remove the `known_hosts` entry:**

```
$ ssh-keygen -f "/home/mike/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "bitbucket.org"
# Host bitbucket.org found: line 2
/home/mike/.ssh/known_hosts updated.
Original contents retained as /home/mike/.ssh/known_hosts.old

$ ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [18.205.93.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/mike/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_31073e5a11 app-155
debug1: no match: conker_31073e5a11 app-155
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:6tASx4IX+FSngemFsQuAIyt0aQ/+fMAyzXBRWRajoBM
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (18.205.93.1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:6tASx4IX+FSngemFsQuAIyt0aQ/+fMAyzXBRWRajoBM.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Warning: the RSA host key for 'bitbucket.org' differs from the key for the IP address '18.205.93.1'
Offending key for IP in /home/mike/.ssh/known_hosts:3
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
Received disconnect from 18.205.93.1 port 22:2: Connection blocked because server only allows public key authentication. Please contact your network administrator.
Disconnected from 18.205.93.1 port 22
```

What my immediately zeros-in on is a message that I have not previously encountered when working with `ssh`:

```
Warning: the RSA host key for 'bitbucket.org' differs from the key 
for the IP address '18.205.93.1'
```

... this *must* be significant ...

Comment: "debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory" FYI, the "key_load_public" line is about the "identity file" line that follows it, not the line before it.

Comment: Thank you, Kenster.  I have now modified the question to include the *entire* output that I now receive when I attempt `ssh`.

Comment: Read your log `WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!`  ... `Host key verification failed.`

Comment: Jeb, "that's part of the issue."  I don't know why this happened.  Furthermore, when I *did* throw away the old host-id in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, the core problem of failure to authenticate persists.  (Usually, no new host-ID is stored.)  So yes, I know what `ssh` is trying to tell me.  But, I can log on to the Bitbucket web-site and very plainly see that the correct SSH public-key is on file there ... as it has been since last October!  I successfully did a `git pull` on Sunday, came in next day and ... (!!)

Comment: I've added yet-more output ... what happens when I remove the `known_hosts` entry.  And, as you'll see from the above, a new message that I have not seen before has just appeared ...

Answer (score 1):

I think that this situation has been explained, therefore **[SOLVED]**, based on information which I found by pursuing this page here on SO:

[Connection blocked because server only allows public key authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59558044/connection-blocked-because-server-only-allows-public-key-authentication)

... where a cryptic comment by "ALuViAn" led me to this page:

https://superuser.com/questions/1466177/connection-blocked-because-server-only-allows-public-key-authentication-putty-f

... whose "Answer #1" *does* appear to relate directly to this issue.

That Answer referred to these two external pages:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Cannot-use-public-key-with-bitbucket-cloud/qaq-p/934114

and:

https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/a4xzrs/key_based_auth_broken_for_all_instances_even_new/

The conclusion appears to be that "there's a man in the middle" (within the company's network security infrastructure).  Overly-enthusiastic network defense software.  This also seems to be confirmed by the fact that *(a)* offices in other cities don't experience the problem, and *(b)* I don't experience it either if I turn on the VPN Client, thus sending all the traffic through a VPN tunnel that emerges "somewhere else."

Hope this helps someone ...

Comment: Most likely, the firewall has turned on ssh_certificate_deep_inspection. To verify this: do ``ssh-keyscan -t rsa any_ip_with_ssh_port_open``. If the obtained public keys are the same (hence not the genuine public key from that ip), you will not be able to login via ssh-key-pairs (you can only login via password). Of course, it can be due to a "man in the middle" attack, though not vey likely.